# How to populate a list of items in another selection using Angular using on select method

Tags: angular

I have two selections one is for sub-counties and the other is a selection for wards. After a user selects the sub-county a ward list will be populated based on the selected sub county. I have a service function called **subCountyWards** That requires the requires the **subcounty.code** value to return a list of the the wards related to the sub county, how do I list the wards when a sub county is selected?

[image]

### Ts File

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.postalCodeList();

    this.subCountyList();

    this.businessRegisterformGroup= this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({
          businessName: ['', Validators.required],
          businessSize: ['', Validators.required],
          numberOfEmployees: ['', Validators.required],
          kraPinNumber: ['', Validators.required],
          vatNumber: ['', Validators.required],
          businessPhoneNumber: ['', Validators.required],
          businessOtherNumber: ['', Validators.required],
          businessEmail: ['', Validators.required],
          businessFaxNumber: ['', Validators.required],
          businessPoBoxNumber: ['', Validators.required],
          businessPostalCode: new FormArray([]),
          businessPostalCodeName: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
          businessTown: ['', Validators.required],
          businessSubCounty: ['', Validators.required],
          businessWard: ['', Validators.required]
        }),
....................................

      subCountyList() {
        this.apiSubCounties.getSubCounties()
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.subcounties = res.data;
          });
      }

      subCountyWards(code) {
        this.apiSubCountyWards.getSubCountyWards(code)
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.wards = res.data;
          });
      }
```

### HTML File

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>SubCounty</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let subcounty of subcounties" [value]="subcounty.name"
        (change)="onSelectionChange($event)">
        {{subcounty.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Ward</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let ward of wards" [value]="ward.name">
        {{ward.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet instead of adding screenshots of your code? This can be unhelpful for users who are unable to view your image due to slow internet speeds or poor readability or for those who are unable to read images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the code to onSelectionChange() on selection:

In HTML:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event.value)">
<mat-option *ngFor="let subcounty of subcounties" [value]="subcounty.code">  // bind subcounty.code instead of name
        {{subcounty.name}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In component:

```
onSelectionChange(event){
    subCountyWards(code);
}

subCountyWards(code) {
    this.apiSubCountyWards.getSubCountyWards(code)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.wards = res.data;
      });
  }
```

Comment: The function is not being triggered even after when I console log it. What could be the issue?

Comment: Which function? And are you getting the correct data in log?

Comment: The onSelectionChange() function

Comment: use (selectionChange) instead of (change)

Comment: I've updated my answer, use (selectionChange)  in mat-select

Comment: This has worked successfully. The event listener needs to be on the mat-select item as described by @acincognito

Answer (score 0):

The event listener needs to be on the `mat-select` item as described here: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api, not on the `mat-option`:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="test()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Ok, suppose I want to pass the selected value to the function i.e test(code)?

Comment: Well if want to get access to the selected value, I would recommend to use formGroups and formControls. And btw I would really appreciate it, if you could select my answer as the correct one, since the other answer just copy-pasted what I wrote, like you mentioned...